# First Normal Form and First and Last Names

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I'm trying to grasp 1NF and am wondering is this following table is 1NF or not. I'm going to assume no because in the colums first_name, last_name, and full_name can be repeated and thus need to be shifted to a new table where there is the columns user_id and first_name, last_name, and full_name. Picture below is a screenshot of the database in reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVbbu.jpg

Comment: It could be 1NF, but it could also be inapplicable (depending on the data). All the xxxx_name fields are not nullable, and some cultures may not *have* firstname / lastname. Also: what would Ludwig van Beethoven have to fill in?

Comment: This is something I recently came across. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: It depends how deep you wanna go. Names are really a mix of name components, that can change over time. Some people only have first names, some only last names, some change their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly could be.

What you are saying with your current design, if it is 1st normal is that a single "entity" (lets just call it a person) is associated with one and only one user record.

If you move the name fields into a separate table, what you are basically saying is that a single "person" could be associated with one or more user records, and that the person, when updating their name, should make the same change to all of their "users"

If you needed a structure like this, the table would look more like:

```
user_id|username|password|email|person_id
```

and you would have a separate table for each "person"

```
person_id|first_name|last_name|full_name
```

1st normal is not about duplicating data.  Just looking at the first name, you very well might have many people with the name "Bob" or "Alice"  Just because that data is duplicated over and over again, is not the same as saying that the table has duplicate data.  The point is that each record should be atomic.

Answer (score 5):

The 1NF is about atomicity, not redundancy (that's what higher normal forms are about). Essentially, if all attributes are atomic, your table is in 1NF.

Obviously, whether a table is in 1NF depends on what you define as "atomic". What "atomicity" actually means is a matter of some controversy, but I'd take a pragmatic case-by-case approach here and simply ask:

***In the context of the problem I'm trying to solve, does it ever make a sense to access<sup>1</sup> any part of the value, or I always access the whole value?***

If I always access the whole, it is atomic in that particular context.

In your example, it is likely you'll want to access `first_name` and `last_name` separately, so `full_name` would be non-atomic and that would be the reason for violating the 1NF. If, however, you know you'll never need to access the first and last name separately, then you could have **just** the `full_name` and still not violate the 1NF.

---

*<sup>1</sup> "Accessing" the value should be understood fairly widely here. It might obviously mean reading it from the database, but could also mean using it in a constraint, or indexing it etc...*