# Storing names in database

Tags: database, database-design

I recently stared to build a small social network, and im a bit lost and confused about storing the names.

So the point is that, this network will be opend for 4 different countries, Hungary, Russia, French, and America.

The bad part is, if i would like to store the names as `first name`, `last name` in the database, that would not be a good idea, because, for example, In Hungary the names are switched, for example, if an Amirecian Citizen signs up as Scott Summers, Scott is the `first name`and Summers is the `last` but for example in Hungarian its totally different, The first name is the last name, and last name is the first, So if Scott where Hungarian, his name would be like this: Summers Scott.

My experience in my country (Hungary) people where really upset when they had their name switched when they signed up for example on facebook, so i would like to avoid that.

I was thinking to give a `full name` field in the table, but thats not a good idea either (in my opinion).

so i would like to ask a more experienced developers opinion if possible, thank you

Comment: Are you going to be working on parts of the name separately? If not, `full name` doesn't seem unreasonable. Why don't you like that approach?

Comment: No, full name is not a good idea. It is not normalized at all - think of sorting by last name - not possible this way (or at least VERY expensive).

Comment: You might also want to read [Falsehoods Programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @Argeman: Whether a database designer chooses to store names as 'full name', 'first name' and 'last name', 'preferred name', or any other way has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @Catcall: Well, that depends on your view. If you assume that the full name is assembled of first and last name in whatever way, than it has to do with normalization. Well, it is not absolutely clear like i stated it, but in my opinion a full-name just doesn't meet first NF. It is just not atomic.

Comment: Full-Name and 1NF is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504604/1338150

Comment: *Atomic* has to do with the dbms, not with you and me. It means that either the dbms ignores the internal structure of a value, or it provides functions to manipulate the pieces. Timestamp values have internal structure, but they're atomic. They're atomic, because the dbms provides functions to manipulate the pieces; you and I don't have to write code to do that. Full names are atomic because the dbms ignores the internal structure. (And it's impossible to write a function that extracts first name from a full name string with the same reliability you can extract minutes from a timestamp.)

Comment: @Catcall: You are right. But assume the following: The full name is usually a combination of first and last name - if you put it that way, it is simply not atomic. It is as damien_the_unbeliever said, every person has 0..n names, and the full name is just a compilation of those names. And you can't compare that to the timestamp - a timestamp is one piece of information, can be displayed differently. This is not the case with a full name. Last name and first name are not correlated - while second and year are just computed results of the timestamp...

Comment: A timestamp is a compound data type; full names (on a global scale, which the web has brought to every one) are a complex data type. The fact that the pieces can't be reliably separated by inspection means the dbms has to return the full name untouched. (You can't tell by inspection whether Martha Neal Baker's first name is "Martha" or "Martha Neal".) If you need the full name and the pieces, you need to store the full name *and* the pieces. On a global scale, the solution isn't "first name plus a space plus last name equals full name".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If* every area you work in has a convention that everyone has a family name, one or more given names, and prefers those names to be formatted in a particular format, **and** you need to process individual parts of the name, then store those facts:

`Family Name`, `Given Name`, `Other Names` and `Preferred Name Format`. I'd also recommend you let them input a `Preferred Name`.

Where you'll usually use `Preferred Name` to address them, and you'll use `Preferred Name Format` to control assembling `Family Name`, `Given Name` and `Other Names` into a format that is acceptable to them in their culture.

Designing the UI to allow them to input these without error is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have one stupid question (sorry i love to ask stupid questions what i dont have experience with), is it a bad idea if instead of <b>Preferred name</b> i would add a <b>display name</b>?

Comment: @LeventeNagy - yep, that's another way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for the table containing the names, and store a flag in the table itself. You can than retrieve the full name from SQL. For example:

```
SELECT 
    IF(nametable.last_name_first,
        CONCAT(nametable.last_name,' ',nametable.first_name),
        CONCAT(nametable.first_name,' ',nametable.last_name)) AS fullname 
    FROM nametable;
```